# How to convert rows into Columns in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset as below:

```
SUBD | X1 | X2
0    |.789|.655
1    |.889|.998
```

I was trying to convert the above dataset in the below format:

```
SUBD  | WK  | Per
0     | X1  | .789
0     | X2  | .655
1     | X1  | .889
1     | X2  | .998
```

I have tried reshape, melt, cast, t, gather function available in R but not able to get the desired output? Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
tmp <- read.delim(text = "SUBD | X1 | X2
0 |.789|.655
1 |.889|.998", sep = "|")
gather(tmp, WK, Per, -SUBD)

#SUBD WK   Per
#1    0 X1 0.789
#2    1 X1 0.889
#3    0 X2 0.655
#4    1 X2 0.998
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `data.table` the following give you exactly what you want.

```
TT <- melt.data.table(TT, id.vars="SUBD", variable.name="WK", value.name="Per")
TT[order(SUBD)]
```

First, convert your data into `data.table`. I created the table based on your example.

```
TT <- data.table(SUBD <- c(0, 1),
                 X1 <- c(.789, .889),
                 X2 <- c(.655, .998))
names(TT) <- c("SUBD", "X1", "X2")
```

Second, melt using `melt.data.table`. Lastly sort as shown. The result is what you intended.

```
   SUBD WK   Per
1:    0 X1 0.789
2:    0 X2 0.655
3:    1 X1 0.889
4:    1 X2 0.998
```

If you want to brush up on melt and cast operations, refer to this article [here](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
library("reshape")
df <- data.frame(SUBD = c(0,1), X1 = c(.789, .889), X2 = c(.655, .998))
reshape::melt(df, id = c("SUBD"))
```